# How can I get rid of the error: package 'turtlebot_gazebo' not found?

Tags: ros

I removed the package `turtlebot_gazebo` and now, whenever I open a new terminal, at the start I get the following message two times:

> [rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot_gazebo' not found

[image: Screenshot of console showing the error messages]

I opened the bash file, but I didn't find any related information. How can I get rid of this message?

Comment: How did you remove the package?

Comment: it was in /src folder so I moved it to outside of catkin_ws environment.

Comment: Have You cleaned devel and build folder ??

Comment: Did you already checked https://answers.ros.org/question/243383/rospack-error-package-turtlebot_gazebo-not-found/ ?

Comment: @MohammadAli thanks bro for your reply yes i did that but the same problem. Dont know what to do ?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg bro I checked that, uninstalled and reinstalled the package but still the same error.

Comment: @Ibrahim try removing your work space from bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Remove source path from your `bashrc` file